# I get the error: posible loss of of precision and i have tried to change it but I can fix it, please help me

Tags: java, variables

I'm just putting the variables and the case that I get the error

```
    Scanner DatoEntrada = new Scanner (System.in);
float AFC, PFC, RC;

case 3:
System.out.println("Ingrese el radio");
RC=DatoEntrada.nextInt();
AFC=3.1416*(RC*RC);
PFC=3.1416*(RC*2);
break;
```

the error says:

```
AFC=3.1416*(RC*RC);
          ^
required: float
found:   double
```

and also in the variable PFC, i have tried changing the enter of the value of the variable RC to nextFloat and double but it doesn´t work, also changing the type of variable to double but when I compile it, it says that te variable is not started in a System.out.print

Answer (score 4):

`3.1416` is a `double` literal.
Multiplying it by an `float` still returns a double, so the result of your entire expression is a `double`.

You can't assign a `double` to a `float` variable (since `double` can hold more than `float`).

Instead, you need to either change the variables to be `double`s, so they can hold the higher-precision result).  Alternatively, you can change the literal to be a `float` literal (by appending `f` to the number), so that the entire thing remains a lower-precision `float`.

Comment: But if a change the variable to be a double then it appears an error that it says that the variable might not been initialized, so i can´t print it

Comment: Or explicitly cast the multiplication result to float.

Comment: @AlbertoReyesCamacho: That's a completely unrelated error.  The only reason you aren't getting that error now is that this other error gets in the way.  What part of that error don't you understand?